# Domain of a nonnatural logarithmic function

Tags: logarithms

How i can find the domain of a nonnatural logarithmic function? I cant found any information about it. For example, the domain of $f(x) = \log_{3}(x+2)$

Comment: You have to impose $x+2>0$ and for a generic base $g(x)$ that is greater than  $0$ and different of $1$ (and this is the case of 3)

Comment: So it is the same procedure for natural logarithmic functions?

Comment: Any two logarithms are proportional.

Comment: Yes but in general if the base is not $e$ you have in addition to check if the base is greater than $0$ and different from 1. Can be useful for you looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm (Look at the 2nd paragraph)

Comment: So, the domain of the example is (-2, infinite)

Comment: @NicolásCastellanos yes! All works: look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_3%28x%2B2%29

Comment: @NicolásCastellanos Anyway if you want to look only at logarithm in natural base you can use the change of base rule

Comment: https://pastebin.com/P65Wj7Qf

Comment: Please view the link

Comment: @Nicolás Castellanos Sorry honestly I can't understand what you want to mean with this link... Can you  explain it specifically?

Comment: @pawel Do you openned the link?

Comment: @pawel If you dont understand the text, resume: How to solve log((6x+2)/5)

Comment: You have simply to impose $\frac{6x+2}{5}>0$ (the base in this case is $e$ surely $>0$ and $\neq 1$). So  $\frac{6x+2}{5}>0\iff 6x+2\iff x>\frac{-1}{3} $. Is it what you are interested in?

Comment: @pawel Yes, very thanks